# How to add additional functionalities?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I got a simple JavaScript based blog . First have a look at the below codes and I will ask my question.

Index.html have the following codes in its body

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="blog/config.js"> </script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="blog/single.js"> </script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="blog/posts.js"> </script>
```

config.js has

```
//This is the configuration file of the blog system.
//change these variables to suit your style and needs 
var head = "h2"; //the heading style, ex. h1, h2, ect. use "h2" rather than "<h2>"
var text = "text"; //the text style, from your style sheet, it's in a <div> tag
var divider = "<hr>"; //the division between posts
var newer = "newer"; //the class for the link to the next newest page
var older = "older"; //the class for the link to the next oldest page
var pageclass = "page"; //the class for the text that displays the page number
var dateclass = "date"; //the class for the date
var pagesize = 4; //the number of posts on each page
var navclass = nav; //the configuration for the navigation`
```

posts.js

```
var posts = 1; //add 1 to this after adding a post. should be equal to the id of the newest post.
initblog(posts);
var id = 1; //make sure that this number is one greater than the one below it
var date = "mm/dd/yyyy"; //The date of the post
var heading = "Post 1"; //The title
var entry = ""; //reset the string
//don't worry about formatting and stuff like that, the system takes care of it all for us.
//VV your entry VV
entry += "<p>Wow, this post is on another page, If you have this many real posts, congratulations!</p>";
//^^ The most important part ^^
add_entry(id,date,heading,entry); //adds the entry to the blog
```

single.js

```
var maxpost;
function initblog(posts){
    maxpost = posts;
    var address = window.location.search;
    if (address.substring(0, 1) == '?') {
        page = address.substring(1);
    } else{
        window.location = "post.html?" + posts;
    }

    page = parseInt(page);
    if (page > maxpost){
        page = maxpost;
    }

    if (page < 1){
        page = 1;
    }   

}
function add_entry(id,date,heading,entry) {
for (i=page;i>page - 1;i--){
    if (id == i){
        var entrytext = "";
        entrytext += "<div class=" + text + ">";    
        entrytext += "<" + head + ">";
        entrytext += "<a name=" + id + "></a>";
        entrytext += "<span class='date'>[" + date + "]</span> ";
        entrytext += heading;
        entrytext += "</" + head + ">";    
        entrytext += entry;
        entrytext += "</div>" + divider;
        document.write(entrytext);
    }
}
}

 function pages(){
entrytext = ""
entrytext += "<table class=\"nav\"><tr>";
entrytext += "<td width=25% class = " + newer + ">&nbsp";
if (page < maxpost){
entrytext += "<A HREF=javascript:prev()>Newer Posts </A>";
}
entrytext += "</td><td width=50% class = " + pageclass + "><br><A HREF=javascript:newest()> Back to Index</A></td>"; 
entrytext += "<td width=25% class = " + older + ">&nbsp";
if (page-1 > 0){
    entrytext += "<A HREF=javascript:next()>Older Posts</A>";
}
entrytext += "</td></table>";
entrytext += "";
document.write(entrytext);
}

function next(){
page = page - 1;
if (page < 1) {
    page = page + 1;
}
window.location = "post.html?" + page;
}

function prev(){
page = page + 1;
if (page > maxpost) {
    page = maxpost;
}
window.location = "post.html?" + page;
 }

function newest(){
window.location = "index.html?" + maxpost;
 }
```

Well , this is the whole blog script .  I ain't added styles and you may see the comments on each lines for simplicity.
This blog doesn't have options to add title and meta description , keyword etc. Due to the style of applying it can do nothing outside the body tag.

1 . How to add an option to take/load titles?
2 . How to add the feature to load meta tag?

Don't tell me to edit and add titles on the template (index.HTML) , because that make no sense

Comment: What kind of metadata?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "take/load" titles? You have "heading" attribute. Do not solve it your problem?

Comment: Sorry not metadata , they are meta tags ( <meta description="example..."> )

Comment: This is a blog script , so each posts should have its own titles and meta tags . But here , it hasn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see the heading block is for the title of the blog. All you need is just making it more visible.

```
    var entrytext = "";
    entrytext += "<div class=" + text + ">";    
    entrytext += "<h1>" + heading + "</h1>";
    entrytext += "<" + head + ">";
    entrytext += "<a name=" + id + "></a>";
    entrytext += "<span class='date'>[" + date + "]</span> ";
    entrytext += "</" + head + ">";    
    entrytext += entry;
    entrytext += "</div>" + divider;
    document.write(entrytext);
    document.title = heading;
```

This will solve your problem about titles.

Regarding to meta tags, usually (actually by standard) meta tags are written betweeen <head> tags in HTML. To make it SEO compilant you need add them into these tags. More detailed: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

But, if this code is generated on client-side. There is no meaning to generate it, because search engine will not parse on-fly generated meta tags. Because it's executed on browser.

Comment: You don't understand, what I am trying to say . Titles means the texts inside in <title> tag  ( <title>This is a sample Title </title> ) , which will be appear in browser's URL box . Everything should be in head tags for SE0 optimization . I am ready to give the sources if you're willing to help me.

Comment: In this case add document.title = heading line

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: Got it . Now it looks cool . but still meta tags needs your attention. Any idea ?

Comment: Hey , I have found some code . `document.head.innerHTML = "<meta name=" description" content="this is a sample desc">";`   It works too. But after applying it , my sites structure is changing . Do you have any idea why ?